# Как теперь найти и вывести на печать номер и элементы строки, в которой находится максимальный элемент матрицы? Язык C++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Как теперь найти и вывести на печать номер и элементы
строки, в которой находится максимальный элемент матрицы? Язык C++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Введите размерность матрицы" << endl;
    cout << "N=";
    cin >> N;
    double** A = new double* [N];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        A[i] = new double [N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            A[i][j] = j * j - i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из этого:

```
A[i][j]=j*j-i;
```

искать не надо, максимальный элемент находится в нулевой строке. Её вывод:

```
for (j=0; j<N; j++)
   cout <<A[0][j]<<" ";
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: а как теперь вывести на печать номер и элементы строки где он находится?

Comment: Добавил. Точно так же, как выводили все другие строки, только первый индекс зафиксирован